# Are both "out of the city" and "outside the city" correct and natural?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

*Where do you live?*

*A bit out of the city.* / *A bit outside the city.*

Are both these correct? Are they equally natural?

Comment: I drove a little way out of the city. I live a little way outside the city. _Bit_ is not (to me) a very natural word to use here, but I would use _out_ only with verbs of movement.